# Существуют ли готовые решения для реализации свайпа под углом?

Tags: java, android, swipe

Я хочу реализовать swipe объекта под углом. Что-то типо того, что представлено на этих фотографиях[image][image: свайп вправо][image: свайп влево]

Comment: ItemTouchHelper + RotateAnimation